# Trying to remove off of Two ListBoxes with the same index however this conflicts with other code?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listbox

I have two list boxes, Ingredients and quantity. I want to click one list box and when pressing delete this will remove the item in the index of these listboxes however it always complains about the index being -1. Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub Ingredients_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Ingredients.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Dim IndexVal As Integer = Ingredients.SelectedIndex
    'Dim TextInIndexOfIngredients As String = Ingredients.Items(IndexVal).ToString()
    'Dim TextInIndexOfQuantity As String = Quantity.Items(IndexVal).ToString()
    'MsgBox("Recipe:" + TextInIndexOfIngredients + " Quantity:" + TextInIndexOfQuantity)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Ingredients.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
        If Ingredients.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            Ingredients.Items.Clear()
        Else
            Dim index As Integer = Ingredients.SelectedIndex
            Ingredients.Items.RemoveAt(index)
            Quantity.Items.RemoveAt(index)
        End If


    End If
End Sub
```

No idea how to solve this, have tried everything. clearing it works fine.

Comment: Does no one have a solution to this problem?

Comment: It will be -1 if there is no item selected. The SelectedIndex is zero-indexed, meaning that it starts counting from 0. The first item is #0.

Comment: I solved this some how by using removeat